# how to call an item of an multidimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
i = 0
lines.each do |l|
  array[i] = l.split(',')
  i+=1
end
```

and I want call `$array[1][3]` like in php, but it didnt worked. I've google it over hours now, and can't find a solution.

Comment: When you say "didn't work" you didn't actually tell us when wrong. Did you get the wrong answer, did you see an error message, did your computer explode into a shower of purple elephants?

Comment: sry i had a windows related error, i started my ubuntu and it worked my way

Answer (score 2):

First of all a few enhancements to your codez:

```
# initialize your vars
array = []
lines.each do |l|
  array << l.split ',' # use the << operator
end
```

Now in ruby the dollar symbol for arrays is not necessary, it denotes global variables and it's not good practice to use them.

You should access your variable like this: `array[1][3]`.

You can make your code a one liner in ruby1.9:

```
array = lines.each_line.map {|l| l.split ',' }
```

Comment: what's wrong with the ruby 1.8 way?

array = lines.collect{|l| l.split ','}

Comment: @Simon nothing particularly, I added that just as a bonus refactor. It's presuming that lines is a string could be also rewritten for 1.8.7 like `array = lines.split("\n").map{|l| l.split ',' }`.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that calling `array[6][3]` returns something like `Error: method [] undefined for nil`, then do this instead:

```
array[6].to_a[3]
```

Whenever either the row (6) or the column (3) is out of range, it gives back `nil`. `to_a` ensures that, even when the row is out of range, it still gives an empty array so that search for column does not return an error.